# Extracting a substring from a large string in Erlang

Tags: string, erlang

I need to search for a substring in a string and return that if it is there in the string.
What is the best way to do that in Erlang? Note that i dont know the place that substring happens in the bigger string so i need to do a search for that.

Comment: everything you will find in the `string.erl` module in erlang `stdlib`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
> re:run("foobarbaz", "bar", [{capture, first, list}]).
{match,["bar"]}
```

See [the documentation for re:run/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#run-3) for more information.  In particular you may find that a different `capture` option suits your need.

Or if you don't need all the features of regular expressions, [string:str/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#str-2) might be enough:

```
> string:str(" Hello Hello World World ", "Hello World").
8
```

Answer (score 3):

This small function may help you. It returns true if the small string can be found in the big string, otherwise it returns false.

```
string_contains(Big, Small)->
    string:str(Big, Small) > 0.
```